# Error Uncaught TypeError: e.target.className.indexOf is not a function at HTMLDocument.mouseup (translator.js:433) in angular

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I have one modal bootstrap, when i click in one svg to edit my data i receive:

> Uncaught TypeError: e.target.className.indexOf is not a function at
>   HTMLDocument.mouseup (translator.js:433)

My svg:

```
  <svg data-dismiss="modal" class="cursorPointer" (click)="editaDescricao(sortedData[i])" fill="darkorange" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M3 17.25V21h3.75L17.81 9.94l-3.75-3.75L3 17.25zM20.71 7.04c.39-.39.39-1.02 0-1.41l-2.34-2.34c-.39-.39-1.02-.39-1.41 0l-1.83 1.83 3.75 3.75 1.83-1.83z"/><path d="M0 0h24v24H0z" fill="none"/></svg>
```

my importations:

```
<body>

      <!-- Font Awesome -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css">
      <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <!-- Material Design Bootstrap -->
      <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.4/css/mdb.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap tooltips -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.4/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
      <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <!-- MDB core JavaScript -->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdbootstrap/4.7.4/js/mdb.min.js"></script>

  <app-root>
  </app-root>

</body>
```

Angular v7.2, i think in v6 this don't happen.

@Edit:

Part of my modal:

```
div class="modal fade" id="modalPesquisa" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="false" role="dialog">

    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Pesquisa de descrição de produtos</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body">
             //svg comes here
```

Comment: I think you need to show more code, the error occurs inside this function? editaDescricao() maybe if you show the component and its template would help

Comment: No, is when the modal close, but if i remove the data-dismiss the error disappear. I remove the (click) function and the error continue.

Comment: I can't put the full code of my modal because i receive error that is missing characters in the post.

Comment: check my edit, i added some new code

Comment: Ok, so, you have that error only when the modal is dismissed right? The error shows the  HTMLDocument.mouseup problem, I don't know the relation of mouseUp event and your modal seeing your code. You are using bootstrap modal, have you consider use Angular Material instead of Bootstrap? Sorry, only seeing this It's very difficult to help, if you can add an stackblitz code to reproduce will be helpful

Comment: i think is something near the svg. when i change the svg by a icon the error disappear. why? i don't think idea... i wonder why

Comment: I got same issue, I have solved it by adding img tag and in it added svg icon path. It solved for me.

Answer (score 5):

if you have a mate extension in your google chrome you need to remove it I think it will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

disabling mate-translate extension works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).